# Redirecting output from trace() function used in XPath queries

Tags: xpath, redirect, saxon

I'm using Saxon Home Edition dlls for evaluation of XPath expressions.
Is there a way to redirect output from trace() function to another window/message box that I specify?
I'm creating a new textwriter object and setting console error to this object using:

```
Console.SetError(textwriterobj)
```

After this, I call the saxon xpath query evaluate function, but the results of trace() function don't come in the textwriter object but the default console of my application.
However, using Console.Write redirects the messages to my textwriter object correctly.
It seems that the saxon dlls are still using the default application console for sending the trace results, any pointers on how I could redirect it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of question asked and answered here:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/forums/forum/94027/topic/5144403

Please don't ask the same question on multiple forums.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply Mr. Kay.Asking on multiple platforms to maximise the chance of receiving the answer, and since these two forums are not related (as far as I know), didn't think it was wrong.